# Rails 4 trying to parse POST JSON in controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I have a controller with the path to create a row in my db

The page model.js has a function that does an ajax post

```
function autoSaveVideo(playPos){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/video_views/create",
            dataType: "json",

            data: { 
                play_position: 0,
                user_id: $('.user_id').text(),
                video_id: $('.video_id').text()
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data
            }
        });
        setTimeout(autoSaveVideo, 6000);
```

I then have the controller

render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => :json

this sends a successful 200 response

but if I add to the video_views_controller.rb <-- edit and note: not Videos controller

jData = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

I get an 795: unexpected token, in the console

how do I parse it so that I can access the data object?

Comment: You can get your data in params check with  `params[:data]` in controller.

Comment: It's a different controller to the controller from which I am sending... I am sending from the js of the video page (and thus videos_controller) to the controller view_views_controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardeep is almost correct. You'll need to use `params` method to access the values in the data object you sent. So params['play_position'], etc.

It is a security best practice to explicitly list the keys you're expecting and permitting. See Rails Guide for strong parameters.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Thanks Richard - that helped out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your data in params check with `params[:data]` in controller. Everything you send with request will received as params in controller. Only data you send in headers not received as params.

Comment: Just to be clear I am sending data from my page to my server which is supposed to post the json data to a different model - there wouldn't be any params? After doing what you suggested I got a TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String)

Comment: I think you just want to post some data to videos_views controller's create method.

Comment: if I do that I have to create an action in the videos_views controller that isn't a create action for the videos_views. I'm creating a new row for 'VideoViews' table not 'Videos' table. Yes I could possible do it in the vidoes controller and create a separate action there but I intended to use the videoviews controller. I still need to know why it isn't parsing correctly.

Comment: Ok I have params[:user_id] and so on and that works - however I am getting nan for user_id & video_id

Comment: Thanks for helping out Pardeep - I messaged you on google hangouts to talk to about some of your other github projects so message me when you get a change. Cheers.